# How to access BIOS in a dell latitude computer?

Tags: boot, bios

In Dell Latitude with Windows 10 Home I have putted a Ubuntu 22.04 iso file in a disk-on-key and I wish to boot the computer with that disk on key.

I have tried to reset the computer several times and each time pressing repeatedly on these keys:

- <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>
- <kbd>Insert</kbd>
- <kbd>Esccape</kbd>
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Yet the bios won't come up so I can't choose to boot the disk on key.

How to access BIOS in a dell latitude computer?

Comment: What happens instead? Does the computer boot Windows? If that's the case, which Windows version? 7/8/10/11?

Comment: @DanielB the computer boots Windows 10 Home.

Comment: @DanielB you are asking the wrong question, what windows version is irrelevant. He is trying to get the BIOS startd up

Comment: Make a video of your laptop starting up, and watch the video back pausing it, see if it says something like Press F2, or Press F10   The keys inser tand backspace are irrelevant. And to test a key, keep tapping it repeatedly

Comment: Is Fast Boot enabled in Windows 10? If yes, try to access Firmware Settings by going to Recovery Options -> Restart Windows from within Windows 10. Fast Boot sort of prevents keyboard usage during POST.

Comment: @barlop The version is very relevant because only recent versions can reboot to firmware setup. // In Windows, press Shift while clicking on any reboot option (no need to log in). On the menu that appears, select _Troubleshooting_, then _Extended_ (or _Advanced_, not sure), then _UEFI firmware setup_ if available. If not, this way unfortunately won’t work.

Comment: Why are you going into windows to go to the BIOS? Maybe if currently in Windows and it's a recent version then ok. But  A computer user should be able to get to the BIOS without having to go into Windows.  Especially if they are interested in working with different operating systems. A limitation of having to load windows to get to the BIOS is ridiculous.

Comment: It’s not ridiculous, it’s just a fact. With Fast Startup enabled, the firmware _must not_ allow other boot devices lest the hibernated status get corrupted. And indeed if the firmware is set to “super fast boot” (unrelated to Windows Fast Startup, very rare but delivers the original UEFI promise), it will not even initialize the keyboard driver.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is associated with me using an external keyboard (Logitech K120).

When I pressed <kbd>F2</kbd> from the laptop's keyboard (which I generally don't use) I did succeed to enter the BIOS.

There was one time when pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> from my external keyboard did work, it happened after exiting the BIOS (after going in to it with the laptop's own keyboard) and booting again but in other two tries <kbd>F2</kbd>  from my external keyboard didn't bring me to BIOS.

To sum it all up, I will try <kbd>F2</kbd> from the laptop's own keyboard next time.